# How to put Ruby Variable inside of Regex Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, variables, grep

I'm running the grep method to filter by pattern matching. This is an example code.

```
companies.grep /city/
```

However, ruby isn't allowing me to input the `area_code` withing the block inside the rails view.  Instead, I'm forced to hardcode it like so:

```
companies.grep /miami/
```

Keep in mind, city is a variable. For example,

```
city = miami
```

However, it updates.  Do you know how can I pass a variable through the grep method?

Also, I tried companies.grep `/#{city}/`, but it didn't work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
companies.grep /#{city}/
# or
companies.grep Regexp.new(city)
```

In case of simple alpha-numeric query, this should suffice; but it is better to get into practice of escaping those, if you don't intend to have regexp operators. Thus, better version:

```
companies.grep /#{Regexp.escape city}/
# or
companies.grep Regexp.new(Regexp.escape city)
```

Comment: Those two are equivalent. There is zero chance for `/#{city}/` to fail and `Regexp.new(city)` to succeed, given same `city` (unless someone went and redefined `Regexp` to mess with you).

Comment: However, it did in the rails view while Regexp.new(city) succeeded